# How to fix the read only error on lima vm

Tags: docker, apple-m1, oracle19c

Getting read only file system error when try to create local repository for docker. [1]
I used this installed lima [2] over Macbook Air M1 (Apple chipset)

```
chown: changing ownership of 'oracle-19c/.DS_Store': Read-only file system
chown: changing ownership of 'oracle-19c/oradata': Read-only file system
chown: changing ownership of 'oracle-19c/': Read-only file system
```

Any one know how to resolve this. I have change the permission to read write with 'getInfor' option by selecting the relevant  folder.

[1] https://registry.hub.docker.com/r/doctorkirk/oracle-19c
[2] https://github.com/lima-vm/lima

Answer (score 10):

By default the home is read only.
You may try write on `/tmp/lima`, this should work.

To make home and other paths writeable by default, do the following:

1. Edit the file and set write: true under mount section

   ```
   $ vim ~/.lima/default/lima.yaml
   ```
2. Then restart lima

   ```
   limactl list #this lists all running vms 
   limactl stop default #or name of the machine 
   limactl start default #or name of the machine
   ```

Further infos: https://github.com/lima-vm/lima/blob/41fd9cc6a1e2bac73666e1f2b11604c7c42227dc/pkg/limayaml/default.TEMPLATE.yaml#L33-L41

Answer (score 2):

As @Dunick answered, We should add a writable feature to lima.yaml  for each mounted volumes

```
 - location: "~"
 writable: true
 - location: "/tmp/lima"
 writable: true
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, using macOS Sonoma, and if you want to do it faster, but a bit insecure:

```bash
# Bash or zsh
limactl edit your-instance-name --mount-writable
```